# Integration: How to generally pick "$u$" in substitution and some specific examples I had to do

Tags: integration, substitution

I have been doing integration by substitution. And I wonder whether there is a general method or approach, as to what I can pick as $u$. I have had these specific tasks, were the teacher gave a hint as to what $u$ should be and the rest we had to solve ourselves:

1. $\int\ln(1+\sqrt{x})\,dx\quad$ Hint: $u=1+\sqrt{x}$.
2. $\int \frac{e^{\sqrt{x}}}{\sqrt{x(1+e^{\sqrt{x}})}}\,dx\quad$, Hint: $u=1+e^{\sqrt{x}}$
3. $\int \frac{x}{\sqrt{a^2-x^2}}\,dx\quad$ Hint: $u=a^2-x^2$

But how can he see what should be picked as $u$? My experience is that what is picked for $u$ is that what is the least complex. Which means that picking the entire denominator for $u=\sqrt{x(1+e^{\sqrt{x}})}$ in (2) and the same for (3) $u=√a^2-x^2$, would lead nowhere or would be too complex. Or do you disagree would it be just as good picking the entire denominator in (2) and (3)?

Thank you.

Comment: As far as I'm concerned, I pick whatever method makes the integral simpler.  I can see the choice for 2 and 3.  For the first, I'd probably do integration by parts to eliminate the natural log or x=u^2 to get rid of the square root.

Comment: I just made an edit, please verify that the math expressions are correct as the placement of square roots was not clear.

Comment: Yes its correct.

Comment: There is in general no one system that will tell you how to proceed in u-substitution (integral solving can be a bit of an art in that sense). That being said, substitution allows us to split a nested function into one with less nesting by taking the derivative of the inside. You want that derivative to make the expression simpler.

Comment: You probably meant $u=1+\sqrt x$ for (1), no? For (2), considering the presence of $\dfrac{e^{\sqrt x}}{\sqrt x}$ and what you know about the chain rule for differentiation, a first choice of $u=e^{\sqrt x}$ is natural; adding $1$ to it turns out to clean up the integrand a bit more. The same chain-rule reasoning applies to (3), but there are other substitutions you can use to handle it (e.g. trigonometric).

Comment: Rule of thumb for these (not the only "trick" in the book") is to pick $u$ when $du$ is visibly present.  Having said that, (1) is not obvious to me so maybe I need to practice.

Comment: If you come across an integral in life, there's no good answer. If you come across an integral in school, there's often a finite list of u-sub problem types you can memorize to speed things up.

Comment: In theory, you're free to use whatever substitution you want, no matter how crazy it looks, as long as you do it right. The tricky part is knowing whether or not your substitution would lead anywhere. Sometimes, it isn't obvious and straightforward, and the only way to get some intuitive sense of what substitution to use is to keep practicing.

Answer (score 0):

Too long for a comment.

u substitution is essentially a reverse chain rule. The change rule allows you to take the derivative of a composite function with respect to its argument, then multiply by the derivative of the argument with respect to $x$. u sub does something similar. So you want to focus on i) the argument of a composite function ii) with an eye out for a manipulation of the argument that already has a factor of its derivative in the integrand.

For problem 1, $u=1+\sqrt{x}$. There's no opportunity for part of the argument's derivative to appear in the integrand.

For problem 2, there are multiple possibilities based on that principle. Note $1/\sqrt{x}$ is a factor of the integrand and $\sqrt{x}$ occurs as an argument multiple times. $(\sqrt{x})'=1/2\sqrt{x}$ So $u=\sqrt{x}$ is a good choice, though not the best.

$\frac{e^{\sqrt{x}}dx}{\sqrt{x(1+e^{\sqrt{x}})}}=\frac{e^udu}{2\sqrt{1+e^u}}$

Then you can apply the same principle again. The only composite function now is $\sqrt{1+e^u}$ and conveniently its derivative is a factor of the integrand already in place. This suggests we let $v=1+e^u\implies dv=e^udu$

$\frac{e^udu}{2\sqrt{1+e^u}}=\frac{dv}{2\sqrt{v}}$

Using $v=1+e^{\sqrt{x}}$ would have cut to the chase, but either way is pretty quick.

Problem 3 is pretty clear. There's only one composite function and a scalar multiple of its derivative is in the integrand.

In general, substitution takes $\int f(g(x))g'(x) dx$ to $\int f(u)du$ via $u=g(x)$.

So good rule of thumb focus on arguments of the composite function and multiples of its derivative.